# bad operand types for binary operator "==" in java

Tags: java, debugging, operands

i try to see if the char of a string == "1" but it shows error as bad operand types for binary operator.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Q3 {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter any number: ");
        int num = scan.nextInt();
        int length = String.valueOf(num).length();
        int reverse = 0;
        if (length<=3) {
            while(num != 0) {  
                int remainder = num % 10;  
                reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;  
                num = num/10;  
        }       
        String word = "";
        String numword=String.valueOf(reverse);
        char character = numword.charAt(0);
        System.out.println(character=="1");}}}
```

edit: i debugged it. i had to use '' instead of "" thanks for the answer everyone....

Comment: Try `character=='1'` . `"1"` is a `String`, not a `char` .

Answer (score 1):

The double quotes are used to instantiate an Object of type String. In your case you want to compare a Character, which is instantiate with simple quote.

It should do the trick for you :

```
character == '1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Chars in Java are set by quotes instead of double quotes.
Please try

character=='1'

instead.